# MySQL error, Too many connections

Tags: mysql

When I try to see my website, instead of the forum that I was uploaded on the host, this below screen appears :

[image]

me, as the one who bought a domain and a free host, what must do to solve it? As you see above, I even can't login in the Admin page.

Is the origin of problem a bug in the code? or it is a problem with the host server?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a problem with your hosting provider. You should talk to them and give them the exact error.

One fix could be that they need to increase the **max_user_connections** setting.

Answer (score 0):

Too many connection would come if the max no of connection of MySQL is exceeded.This would happen if the connection of MySQL is not properly closed.You can refer the MySQL configuration file my.ini/my.cnf found in the MySQL installation folder for the max value set.

You can change the values of max_connection variable and then rename the iblogfiles found in the data storage location of MySQL  which is referred by data dir in the  my.ini file.Restart the MySQL once.